# Complex Matrix Operator Norm

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $A \in M_{m,n}(\mathbb R).$ How would I show that the operator norm of $A$, the maximum value of $Av$ for $v \in V$ such that $\|v\| = 1,$ is the same whether I take $v$ to be an element of $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$?

I've been working on this problem, and I think that the solution should follow from the definitions, but I'm not sure how it does.

Comment: if $A$ is a complex matrix, that's not true, see $A = \left(\begin{array}{ll} 1&i \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$. if $A$ is a real matrix, with $u,v$ two real vectors then $A (u+iv) = Au+iAv$ hence $\|A(u+iv)\| = \|Au\|+\|Av)\|$. finally compare $\frac{\|Au\|}{\|u\|}$ and  $\frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|}$ to conclude that if $u+iv$ is (one of) the max complex vectors, then $\frac{\|Au\|}{\|u\|} = \frac{\|Av\|}{\|v\|}$ and $u$ and $v$ alone are also the max (real this time) vectors

Comment: when I say 'the max vector' I mean one of the vector maximizing $\frac{\|A w\|}{\|w\|}$

Comment: (I can't edit anymore) replace every $\|.\|$ by $\|.\|^2$

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the Euclidean norm?  I will assume this to be the case.

In that case, think that $$\langle Ax, Ax\rangle = \langle x, A^*A x\rangle,$$
where the inner product is the canonical Hermitian product on $\mathbb{C}^n.$  If $A$ is real, then $A^*=A^T$, and since the ratio

$$\frac{||Ax||^2}{||x||^2}$$ for $x\neq 0$ is attained whenever $x$ is an eigenvector of the highest eigenvalue of $A^*A=A^TA$, clearly one may choose $x$ to be real.  Taking the square root yields $||A||.$

This shows that the value $||A||$ is attained at a real, non-zero vector.